# ASP.NET MVC Model State

Tags: asp.net, modelstate

ModelState.IsValid is returning false for me in my controller.  I know that means one or more model errors were found when model binding.  My question is how do I see the errors?

I noticed that my particular ModelState has 6 items in it.  If I try to do any of these...

```
ModelState[0].Errors[0].ToString()
ModelState[0].Errors[0].ErrorMessage
ModelState[0].Value.AttemptedValue
```

I get this error:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary.this[string]' has some invalid arguments
```

Comment: Have you debugged your controller action and actually seen what's inside ModelState?

Comment: Can you check the .InnerException of these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indexor into the ModelState is a string (usually the property name of the offending model or name of the html element).

If you check the MSDN docs for the [ModelState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstate.aspx) class, you'll see that it has an Errors collection that will allow you to iterate over the error items (which are [ModelError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelerror.aspx) instances) to see what caused them.

Answer (score 2):

in controller;

```
ModelState.AddModelError("username", "Bad username");
```

in view;

```
 <%= Html.ValidationMessage("username") %>
```

also

```
<%= Html.ValidationSummary() %>
```

Html.ValidationSummary() might be what you are looking for.